# Accessing properties of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, office-interop, outlook-addin

I am working on an Outlook add in application, and I am unable to properly access properties of the `MailItem` object.
For example, if I type an email address in the "To" box, the following code does not return any values in the debugger:

When I try to examine the recipients count property in the immediate window, I get the following error:

```cs
mailItem.Recipients.Count
```

> *'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Count(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, System.Func)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context*

How can I get access to the properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **command window** or **immediate window** see the `Recipients` collection as an `object`, not a specific Outlook embedded type (*`Outlook.Recipients`*). The only way to resolve this is to make the type `dynamic` before accessing its members.

#### `((object)MailItem.Recipients).Count` generates the error:

> (*`System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Count(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, System.Func)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context*).

#### `((Outlook.Recipients)MailItem.Recipients).Count` generates the following error advising you to use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx):

> *Embedded interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipients' is defined in both 'MyOutlookAddIn.dll' and 'Outlook.dll'. Some operations on objects of this type are not supported while debugging. Consider casting this object to type 'dynamic' when debugging or building with the 'Embed Interop Types' property set to false.*

#### This is what you are after to access the ComObjects `Outlook.Recipients` properties:

```cs
((dynamic)MailItem.Recipients).Count
```